# How to remap colors in a DrawingBrush?

Tags: wpf

Say that I have a `DrawingBrush` that has three colors hard-coded, i.e. a border, a foreground, and a background.

[image: EventIcon]

```
<!-- Resource -->
<DrawingBrush x:Key="EventIcon" Stretch="Uniform">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup.Children>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF9200CE" Geometry="F1 M 51.2119,61.4688L 43.4193,61.4688L 43.4194,29.318L 27.8341,29.318L 27.834,61.4688L 20.0414,61.4688L 35.6267,77.1353L 51.2119,61.4688 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFB400FF" Geometry="F1 M 44.4789,64.2014L 40.2667,64.2667L 40.13,29.318L 27.8341,29.318L 27.834,61.4688L 20.0414,61.4688L 33.8667,75.1467L 44.4789,64.2014 Z "/>
                <GeometryDrawing Geometry="F1 M 51.2119,61.4688L 43.4193,61.4688L 43.4194,29.318L 27.8341,29.318L 27.834,61.4688L 20.0414,61.4688L 35.6267,77.1353L 51.2119,61.4688 Z ">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        <Pen Thickness="2" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round" LineJoin="Round" Brush="#FF3D0033"/>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFFFFFF" Geometry="F1 M 33.7559,53.2538L 32.6202,40.9989L 32.6202,35.3362L 37.3531,35.3362L 37.3531,40.9989L 36.2333,53.2538L 33.7559,53.2538 Z M 32.6202,59.6771L 32.6202,54.9442L 37.3531,54.9442L 37.3531,59.6771L 32.6202,59.6771 Z "/>
            </DrawingGroup.Children>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>

<!-- Usage -->
<Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="{StaticResource EventIcon}" />
```

**Question**
What would be the best approach to be able to change these colors from the parent `Rectangle`, yet still have a default fallback?

As I write this question, I have thought to two possible solutions...

**Possible Solution #1**
Using a `RelativeSource` binding to connect each to their equivalent property, e.g. `{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:type Rectangle}}` however:

1. `Rectangle` being a `Shape` does not have `BorderBrush` properties;
2. I could not provide a default value. Specifying `FallbackValue` in the binding won't work as the binding would resolve and take it's default value. (**Edit:** As I write this, I thinking that I could possibly use the `NullValue` property).

**Possible Solution #2**
Write an attached property that takes an array of colors/brushes and then have a converter to map it to the `GeometryDrawing.Brush`. Provide a default value using the `Binding.IsNull` property as I can guarantee a null value is return if it cannot map if the attached property is null or that color is not remapped.

Comment: Rectangle has `Stroke` and `Fill` instead of `BorderBrush` and `Background`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a [dynamic resource reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942.aspx), define the defaults at the application level (`Application.Resources`) and change them locally by adding brushes with the same key in some control's resources.

Comment: That could work; usually avoid using `DynamicResource` due to it's performance implications. ... I would prefer a more localized solution where default colors are declared close their usage. The icons are created in a Expression Design and whilst I try to pick colors from a common palette to keep a consistent design that is no always possible.

Comment: @DennisRoche: A side-note: You'll probably want to set [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) to `false` on the brush otherwise the same instance is used everywhere.

Comment: Thanks @H.B. I will continue to investigate the available options. Still not 100% sold on using `DynamicResource`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create attached properties for each of the three colours, and then create a default style to give them default values.

You could then override these values in your `Rectangle` declaration if you wanted using normal attached property syntax.

The only other way I can think of is to have the colours as static resources, which you could recreate in your `Rectangle`'s resource dictionary if you wanted to override.